# Locking the disk drives with a password

Tags: windows-7

How can I lock a particular disk drive (`C:`, `D:` or `E:`) in my computer with passwords? Is this possible in Windows7?

Answer (score 11):

You can try [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.org/), which will encrypt it. Of course, if you lose the password, there is no way to retrieve the info.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Bit Locker is an option although it is unfortunately not available in all versions of Windows 7, details here:

[Windows 7 Bit Locker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/bitlocker)

(Personally, I would probably use TrueCrypt)

Answer (score 2):

How about just putting the files on those drives into folders and then setting the permissions so only your user account (with a password nobody else knows) has access?